# change innerHTML using javascript substring

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make read more button using javascript substring but my code is not working, I can hide text but, can not show more on click

```
<p class="pr">More than 200</p>
<button class="btn">Read more</button>
```

```
<script>
  var pr = document.querySelectorAll('.pr');
  var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

  for (var i = 0; i < pr.length; i++) {
    if(pr[i].innerHTML.length >= 200){
      var showLess = pr[i].innerHTML.substring(0, 200);
      pr[i].innerHTML = showLess;
    }
    btn.addEventListener('click', showMore);

    function showMore(){
      var showMore = pr[i].innerHTML.substring(0, );
      pr[i].innerHTML = showMore;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: When you change .innerHTML, it gets permanently changed. Try storing the original text in js or some hidden element and use that to manipulate .innerHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should store the text inside a variable, because if you then shorten it, javascript doesn't remember the first text:

```
var text = pr[i].textContent; // make this the first thing in the for loop
```

Then, instead of referring to `pr[i].innerHTML.substring`  use `text.substring` (only when getting the value, not when setting it).

I hope this will work, haven't tested it (writing on my phone).

Comment: Thank you for simple explain :)

Comment: This probably will not work for multiple texts though, because with each iteration of the loop, the variables change and it would only work for the last element.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the `innerHTML` with the short string so you need to hold the original value in a variable. In my snippet I save the original string in the `more` variable.

Furthermore the `document.querySelectorAll('.btn');` returns a `NodeList` object on which you cannot attach an event listener directly, you need to iterate through each node and add it to those.

In your code you were getting a `TypeError` on the `addEventListener` call so the callback was not attached to the `click` event.

Lastly, do not use the `innerHTML` use `textContent` as `innerHTML` is a costly operation. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText) .

> Element.innerHTML returns HTML, as its name indicates. Sometimes
>   people use innerHTML to retrieve or write text inside an element, but
>   textContent has better performance because its value is not parsed as
>   HTML. Moreover, using textContent can prevent XSS attacks.

```js
var pr = document.querySelectorAll('.pr');
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

for(let i =0; i<pr.length; i++){
  let more = pr[i].textContent;
  if(more.length >= 5){
    let showLess = more.substring(0, 5);
    pr[i].textContent = showLess;
  }
  btn.forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', () => {
     console.log(more);
     pr[i].textContent = more;
  }));
  
}
```

```html
<p class="pr">More than 200</p>
<button class="btn">Read more</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version using `Id` instead of class.

```js
let pr = document.getElementById('pr');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let actualText = pr.innerHTML; 
if(pr.innerHTML.length >= 200){
  pr.innerHTML =  pr.innerHTML.substring(0, 200);
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => { pr.innerHTML = actualText;});
}
```

```html
<p id="pr">This is basic test content which length is More than 200, This is basic test content which length is More than 200, This is basic test content which length is More than 200, This is basic test content which length is More than 200, This is basic test content which length is More than 200, This is basic test content which length is More than 200, This is basic test content which length is More than 200</p>
<button id="btn">Read more</button>
```

And yes you need to store your original text content before updating the `innerHTML` of the element.